# Custom module not working in Magento2

Tags: magento, magento2

I have been trying to setup a basic module in Magento2, it keeps throwing 404 despite doing all the ideal changes. Below is the code related to the module. My vendor name is **Chirag** and module name is **HelloWorld**.

/var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Chirag/HelloWorld/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Chirag_HelloWorld" schema_version="0.0.1" setup_version="0.0.1">
    </module>
</config>
```

/var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Chirag/HelloWorld/etc/frontend/route.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="helloworld" frontName="helloworld">
            <module name="Chirag_HelloWorld" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

/var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Chirag/HelloWorld/Controller/Index/Index.php

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Chirag\HelloWorld\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * 
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        protected $resultPageFactory;
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
        )
        {
            parent::__construct($context);
            $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        }

        public function execute()
        {
            return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        }
    }
}
```

/var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Chirag/HelloWorld/Block/HelloWorld.php

```
<?php
namespace Chirag\HelloWorld\Block;

class HelloWorld extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

}
```

/var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Chirag/HelloWorld/view/frontend/layout/helloworld_index_index.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Chirag\HelloWorld\Block\HelloWorld" name="helloworld" template="helloworld.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

/var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Chirag/HelloWorld/view/frontend/templates/helloworld.phtml

```
<h1> test hello to Magento 2 !! </h1>
```

Any kind of help would be really appreciated.

Comment: hello @Chiragit007, Is it possible to use this module for maintaining REST API call ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below changes led to correct answer for me :

Index controller - magento2/app/code/Chirag/HelloWorld/Controller/Index/Index.php

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Chirag\HelloWorld\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * Show Contact Us page
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->getLayout()->getBlock('helloworld');
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Block - magento2/app/code/Chirag/HelloWorld/Block/Question.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Chirag\HelloWorld\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

/**
 * Main contact form block
 */
class Question extends Template
{
    /**
     * @param Template\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(Template\Context $context, array $data = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_isScopePrivate = true;
    }
}
```

Layout file - magento2/app/code/Chirag/HelloWorld/view/frontend/layout/helloworld_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Chirag\HelloWorld\Block\Question" name="helloworld" template="Chirag_HelloWorld::helloworld.phtml">
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

View template - magento2/app/code/Chirag/HelloWorld/view/frontend/templates/helloworld.phtml

```
<?php echo 'helloworld view'; ?>
<h1> Hello World </h1>
```

Comment: Isn't `_view` is **deprecated** in Magento2 `Action`?

Answer (score 5):

First try to rename `route.xml` to `routes.xml` and see if that fixes the issue.

Next try changing your code in the controller, try change company/module names:

```php
<?php

namespace YourCompany\ModuleName\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

also in your `helloworld_index_index.xml` you can try changing the template decoration to:

```
template="YourCompany_ModuleName::templatename.phtml"
```

lastly you can try changing the `module.xml` `setup_version` declaration to:

```
setup_version="2.0.0"
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the below steps to resolve:

1. You have to change `route.xml` to `routes.xml`
2. Run setup upgrade command:

   `php bin/magento s:up`
3. Go to `your_base_link/helloworld/index/index`
4. Enjoin your result

Answer (score 0):

First of all, rename `route.xml` to `routes.xml`

app/code/Chirag/HelloWorld/etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="helloworld" frontName="helloworld">
            <module name="Chirag_HelloWorld" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Index Controller - app/code/Chirag/HelloWorld/Controller/Index/Index.php

You can't use `__construct` inside the `execute` method and these two should be separated.

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Chirag\HelloWorld\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

class Index extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context      $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

You should use the below format when you are calling the template in layout xml.

eg: `Chirag_HelloWorld::helloworld.phtml`

```
app/code/Chirag/HelloWorld/view/frontend/layout/helloworld_index_index.xml
```

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Chirag\HelloWorld\Block\HelloWorld" name="helloworld" template="Chirag_HelloWorld::helloworld.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

app/code/Chirag/HelloWorld/Block/HelloWorld.php

```
<?php
namespace Chirag\HelloWorld\Block;

class HelloWorld extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function getHelloWorldText()
    {
        return __('Hello World');
    }
}
```

app/code/Chirag/HelloWorld/view/frontend/templates/helloworld.phtml

```
<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getHelloWorldText() ?>
```

Once you done run the below commands to apply the changes.

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
bin/magento c:f
```

Use `-f` as a parameter if you are in developer mode.

Use `bin/magento deploy:mode:show` to check the mode.

Happy Coding!!